# Angularjs check or word exist on url

Tags: angularjs

My goal is get true on angularjs controller if url with #how `htttp://www.example.com#how` or false if url without #how `htttp://www.example.com`.

```
webApp.controller('ctrl',function($scope){

$scope.showHow = ???; // if url with #how == true else false
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this.

```
webApp.controller('ctrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.showHow = window.location.hash.indexOf('how') > 0
}
```

Comment: It's generally better practice to use Angular's `$window` service

Answer (score 1):

You can use $location service

```
webApp.controller('ctrl',function($scope, $location){

$scope.showHow = $location.hash() === 'how'; // if url with #how == true else false
```

See details [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

But in general, if the app should display some content on url changes, the best option would be using [default angular's routing](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) or [ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).